# How can I get a full dump of a REST API

Tags: json, rest, api, csv, dump

I want to have a full dump of a rest API. Now I have to query on everything but I just want to have everything of the API in one file (csv or json).

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no one size fits all answer for this. Every API works differently, and some might have a specific feature for this.

If the service you are using is truly RESTful (as in: uses hyperlinks for everything), you might be able to just use a mirror/spider tool to get all the data, but very few services that advertise themselves as REST really are.

Answer (score -1):

"full dump of a rest API" do you mean you want to have file specification of API? If so, you can a have a look at this tool (http://editor.swagger.io/#/) for describing rest api interfaces.